# How widespread are dead pixels?

Tags: display, lcd, pixels

How widespread is the problem of dead pixels or hot pixels these days?

Has the problem become worse with larger monitors and resolutions or become better with better build quality?

Do any hardware manifactures handle this problem especially well?

Are there any statistics on how many monitors suffer from dead pixel?

Answer (score 8):

Dead pixels aren't very common.

[image]

Comment: You almost got me, there!

Answer (score 2):

I've not seen a dead pixel in ages! I work in a office with nearly 30 dell monitors - no one I complaining of Dead Pixels...

Answer (score 2):

Not very common at all, I haven't seen one in the last 3 or 4 years on 100+ screens

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen one, but my experience is limited to just a few dozen monitors I've had reason to sit in front of over the last six years or so.

While we're on the topic of dead pixels, I found this utility a while back called [Dead Pixel Buddy](http://laptopshowcase.co.uk/downloads.php?id=1) that can help you spot them.

Answer (score 1):

Not gone, my monitor has on in the bottom right hand corner. Not worth sending back, but they still exist. (Samsung somethingorother)

Answer (score 0):

Bought a Dell 22 inch monitor last year which had a couple of dead (stuck) pixels in the center of the screen. After going through their stupid little customer service spiel of "Did you try this? And this? And this? And this? How about this?" to confirm I really had a problem, they overnighted me a new one immediately. New one works fine.